# Reading order of Tolkien's middle-earth books

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, books, tolkiens-legendarium, fantasy-genre

I have these books written by J.R.R. Tolkien:

1. The Silmarillion
2. The Hobbit
3. All three LOTRs

Which reading order is the best to get the complete story?
The one I wrote up above, or?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. *The Hobbit*
2. *The Lord of the Rings*
3. *The Silmarillion*

Chronologically, the events in *The Silmarillion* occur before *The Lord of the Rings* but the writing style will put you off Tolkien and it only touches on the events of *The Lord of the Rings*, focusing instead on the lore and history of Middle-earth.

*The Hobbit* is an excellent place to start however you could jump straight into *The Lord of the Rings* as it explains how the ring came into Frodo's possession.

Comment: Not to mention that the last 20 pages or so of _The Silmarillion_ ("Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age") summarizes all of the other books, ruining a lot of their suspense.